# Can't load capistrano-recipes

Tags: ruby, capistrano, recipe

I've added capistrano-recipes to my Gemfile

```
group :development do
  ...
  gem 'capistrano-recipes',require: false
end
```

Added to my deploy script:

```
require 'capistrano-recipes'
```

The result of bundle list:

```
bundle list | grep capistrano
  * capistrano (2.15.5)
  * capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
  * capistrano-platform-resources (0.1.3)
  * capistrano-rbenv (1.0.5)
  * capistrano-recipes (0.8.0)
```

But when I'm running command like `cap -T` I got error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0-turbo/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano-recipes (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0-turbo/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from ./config/deploy.rb:12:in `load'
```

What might be a problem here? Thanks

Comment: Maybe different Ruby installs? also, i don't see the following even though i see the grep:  ...install cap-recipes --source http://gemcutter.org or "bundle install"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the README](https://github.com/webficient/capistrano-recipes/blob/master/README.rdoc), this is what you should put in your deploy script:

`require 'capistrano_recipes'`

Note that it uses an underscore, and not a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Either install the gem globally

```
gem install capistrano-recipes 
cap -T
```

or just:

```
bundle exec cap -T
```

Comment: with bundle exec same thing